# Cakephp2 filter dates from past

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I'm wondering if it's possible to:

I have some string (10.07.2016-17.07.2016 , 19.07.2016-21.07.2016 , 22.07.2016-29.07.2016 etc... )
dates are separate by "," so for now i want to make array of dates separated by ",".

As result i will use this array to create select dropdown, so user can select data like for example (very generic, not cakephp style but it's just for understanding my question):

```
<select>
   <option>10.07.2016-17.07.2016</option>
   <option>19.07.2016-21.07.2016</option>
   <option>22.07.2016-29.07.2016</option>
</select>
```

But now i'm wondering - how can i first filter this data to remove dates from past ?
Let's say that i have 11.07.2016 in calendar, so i should not see this in select ?

So, my question is - is this possible ? If yes, how should i filter this data? Filter array first using some function, or when i will generate select in form ?

Thanks for ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first convert string into array,

```
$myString = "10.07.2016-17.07.2016, 19.07.2016-21.07.2016";
$myArray = explode(', ', $myString);
```

then use foreach to check if date is in the past

```
foreach($myArray as $element) {
    if(strtotime($element)>strtotime("now")){
       $futureDates[] = $element;
    }
}
```

then you have only future dates for echo in 
`<select><option>...</option><option>...</option></select>`